# Discrete Mathematics Proof odd degree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

Show that for a graph letting r be the number of vertices with odd degree( with an odd number of edges) show that r is even.

Is that about Euler's criterion or is there any other solution?

Comment: What is eular's criticism?

Comment: I think she means Euler's criterion, that $F+V=E+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What do you know about the degree sum ? If $v_i$ are the vertices, and there are $n$ vertices, 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n} d(v_i) = \text{twice the number of edges}
$$
A sum of an odd number of odd numbers is odd...what can you deduce from this? What would the parity of the degree sum be if there were an odd number of vertices with odd degree?